# How to read a specified number of lines in a text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a problem in reading a bigger size file in JAVA. The file which I used to read has the size of **750MB** so when I used to read a file using **BufferedReader**, **Scanner** and **LineNumberReader** all fails to read and leads to **OutOfMemoryError**.

Is there any easy way to read that much bigger size file? Is there any way by skipping some number of lines and read the particular line after skipping of lines.

Code which I used to read the file :

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try
{
     inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
     sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
     while (sc.hasNextLine())
     {
          String line = sc.nextLine();
     }     
     if (sc.ioException() != null)
     {
         throw sc.ioException();
     }
}
finally
{
     inputStream.close();
     sc.close();
}
```

**For example:**

If i think to read a number of lines from **1001 to 2000**, how may I read those particular lines from that bigger size file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: While reading, you keep updating a variable `int line` that you increase after (or before, depending one whether you like 0-based or 1-based numbers) reading the line. Now while that variable is in the range 1001 to 2000, you do something with the line. Else you discard it.

Comment: How would you want to process the file? Line by line? In fixed or variable sized blocks? You might want to read the file in one pass but do the processing in between reading the records and not keep all of them in memory.

Comment: By your way @ErwinBolwidt while i use readline() method itself program throws OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @BhuvaneshWaran Please show your code that generates the error.

Comment: `FileInputStream inputStream = null;
       Scanner sc = null;
       try
       {
           inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
           sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
           while (sc.hasNextLine())
           {
               String line = sc.nextLine();
           }
           if (sc.ioException() != null)
           {
               throw sc.ioException();
           }
       }
       finally
       {
               inputStream.close();
               sc.close();
       }`

Comment: @BhuvaneshWaran A) Put your code in your question, not in a comment. B) are you saying that this code throws an OutOfMemoryError while reading a 750Mb file? I have a very hard time believing that, as you're not storing any data permanently.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt am not storing anything in that file, actually I have to read the file and parse the content for my another logic that's it.

Comment: I second what @ErwinBolwidt mentioned. Since, no data is being stored at all, it seems very far-fetched to get a OutOfMemoryError **in the code you have posted**. Could you please post your actual code with all the logic?

Comment: Still I have not yet started the parsing logic at all. My first goal I have tried to read that bigger size file only. While I read the file by above mentioned code in the line

**String line = sc.nextLine();** 

itself program throws **OutOfMemoryError**.

Comment: The only way I can see this code throwing an OOME is that the file consists of only one (or a few) line(s).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to know where a line ends. That's simply not possible without looking into that file. There is no such function which lets you read at a **certain line number**. If you had asked about a **certain byte position**, the answer would be [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

So you have two options:

1. Every time you want to read at a certain line number, create a new **BufferedReader** (and the underlying streams) and skip all the lines until you have reached your desired one. As the name suggests, the BufferedReader buffers the input source in chunks of 4096 characters - 8192 Bytes. This should be sufficient for the most purposes.
2. If the first option is too slow for your purpose (e.g. you have to read multiple times per second), index your file. What I mean with that: Create a new **RandomAccessFile**, search for all occurrences of line breaks and remember their byte offset. Each time you want to read at a certain line, just reverse look up the byte offset. You could use an array of ints for that, where the index is the line number. This results in a time complexity of O(1) for the lookup. But **be careful**: If the file changes after the indexing, all byte offsets are invalidated. So you have to index the file again.

**Edit**: The second option requires that the file does not contain only empty lines. In that case the lookup-array would also trigger an **OutOfMemoryError**. Each java int needs 4 bytes. If we assume that a line break, written to a file, needs at least 1 byte, the factor would be 4. So when indexing a 750 MB large file the array needs at least 4 * 750 MB = 3 GB. So you have to enlarge the JVM heap with the command line option -Xmx.

**2nd Edit**: As [piet.t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664350/piet-t) stated above, if the file contains only one line, you also have to enlarge the JVM heap with the command line option -Xmx.